# Change media type for responsive media for a specific component

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Hi there! I would like customizing the Rotating Image Component to use the Simple Responsive Banner Component.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CMS component mapping](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/#custom-angular-cms-components)

You will need to add the following to your app.module or the appropriate module:

```
import { BannerComponent } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { CmsConfig, provideConfig } from '@spartacus/core';

...

  providers: [
    provideDefaultConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        RotatingImagesComponent: {
          component: BannerComponent,
        },
      },
    } as CmsConfig),
  ],
```

Alternatively, you can replace the `RotatingImagesComponent` by the `SimpleResponsiveBannerComponent` in the CMS with Backoffice or SmartEdit.